# How can I solve RenderFlex overflowed when I rotate screen?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am new at using Flutter in Android Studio. I tried fixing the RenderFlex overflow error in portrait mode, but once I rotate the screen to landscape it flags again.

I have multiple open classes both stateful and stateless widgets.

I have over 300 lines of code don't know if I can attach it all here.
Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at orientation builder. You can switch the layout based on the orientation or if you are ok with having scroll on landscape you can wrap the main column in a SingleChildScrollView

Example on how to use orientation builder

```dart
body: OrientationBuilder(
  builder: (context, orientation) {
    return GridView.count(
      // Create a grid with 2 columns in portrait mode,
      // or 3 columns in landscape mode.
      crossAxisCount: orientation == Orientation.portrait ? 2 : 3,
    );
  },
),
```

Comment: I tried turning on the auto-rotation of the emulator, I don't know if it really does rotate the whole layout properly. But some widgets came crushing into others.

Comment: It doesn't rotate the layout itself. This builder will let us know if it's portrait or landscape. We can change the layout based on that